# scala Map.getOrElse - how to provide function for default

Tags: scala

Odd...

```
    val h = new HashMap[Long, Int]()

    def mydefault0():Int = 101
    println( h.getOrElse(99, default=mydefault0 _ ) )  // Prints <function0>

    def mydefault1(key:Long):Int = 102
    println( h.getOrElse(98, default=mydefault1 _ ) )  // Prints <function1>
```

The [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashMap) say that default must be of type: => B

If I understand correctly, a no-arg function returning an Int, in this case.

1. Why does the example taking mydefault1 compile, as it takes an argument and so does meet the specification?
2. Why are functions returned, instead of functions being called to yield a default value? Apparently the typesafety has been broken because the getOrElse must return an Int, not a function. (if I misunderstood the docs and incorrectly provided a function where an Int value was required, why did the compiler let me provide a function, instead of an Int?).

**edit**

Clearly:

- extends HashMap and overriding default, or
- using HashMap.withDefault

also let a function by used to specify a default value. What I'd like is to be able to override the default with a function that's provided at the point of performing the lookup (i.e. the function may change during the life of the Map)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The definition of `getOrElse`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Option.html#getOrElse[B%3E:A](default:=%3EB):B):

```
getOrElse[B1 >: B](key: A, default: => B1): B1
```

The `default` argument does *not* take a function—which would be `() => B1`, but a lazily accessed value of type `B1`. This parameterless "function" `=> B1` is also sometimes called thunk. The correct way to use it is as follows:

```
import collection.mutable

val h = new mutable.HashMap[Long, Int]()

def mydefault0(): Int = 101

println(h.getOrElse(99, default = mydefault0()))
```

So what is it that you are seeing with `mydefault0 _`? Clearly, the returned value has type `B1` which must be a common supertype of the map's value type `Int` and the default value's type. The default value's type is `Function0`. If you assign the result, you see that the supertype is `Any`:

```
val x = h.getOrElse(99, default = mydefault0 _ )  // x: Any = <function0>
```

So the mistake is to assume that you must pass in a function, when actually you are stating an expression which is lazily evaluated. The call `mydefault0()` will only be invoked when the default value is needed. Formally, the argument is defined as a [call-by-name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name) argument.

---

**Edit**: Regarding your comment. Call-by-name means that you *do* get a new array each time.

```
val m = Map("foo" -> Array(1, 2, 3))

def myDefault = {
  println("called-default")
  Array(4, 5, 6)
}

val a1 = m.getOrElse("foo", myDefault)  // myDefault not called
val a2 = m.getOrElse("bar", myDefault)  // myDefault called
val a3 = m.getOrElse("baz", myDefault)  // myDefault called
a2 == a3  // false!!
```

Comment: Thanks, that's cleared up my mistake. But back to the question...

So, suppose I wanted a Map[String,Array[Int]], I wouldn't be able to use getOrElse to construct an new default array when the key is missing, right? This would cause each value to be the same object. In other words, there's no provision to provide a function to generate default value at each lookup (overriding the default value of HashMap, or using Map.withDefault doesn't allow me to specify the default-generator as I make the lookup).

Comment: It's very important to correctly understand what by-name parameters are and how they behave (and why they are *not* "lazy"). The most important thing to know about by-name parameters is that the *called* method determines how many times the actual parameter expression is evaluated, and that may be 0, 1 *or more* times. A lazy parameter is evaluated 0 or 1 times only.

Comment: Thanks -- that all makes sense now.